# Console game not working properly

Tags: c++

I am making a simple game for learning purposes mostly and I recently ran into this problem. Keep in mind that I'm still a huge beginner. When I go into the game from the menu and write anything in the "Command Line" I instantly starve and dehydrate. I haven't been able to connect to the internet for a couple of days and I've read through the entire program but I can't find anything wrong.

menu.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
//-------------//
#include "tutorial.h"
#include "game.h"


void menu() {
    std::cout << "-------MENU-------         \n";
    std::cout << " 1.Play                    \n";
    std::cout << " 2.Tutorial                \n";
    std::cout << " 3.Exit                    \n";
    std::cout << "                           \n";
    std::cout << "                           \n";
    std::cout << "                           \n";                     
    std::cout << "Choose Option: ";
    int menuOption;
    std::cin >> menuOption;

    int menuLoop = 0;
    while (menuLoop != 1) {
        if (menuOption == 1) {
            menuLoop = 1;
            play();
        }
        if (menuOption == 2) {
            menuLoop = 1;
            system("CLS");
            tutorial();
        }
        if (menuOption == 3) {
            menuLoop = 1;
            std::cout << "Bye!";
            Sleep(1000);

        }
        if (menuOption > 3)
            std::cout << "\"" << menuOption << "\"" << " is not a valid option.\n";
    }
}
```

game.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinBase.h>

//initiating functions
void step();
void run();
void theme();
void starve();
void die();
void dehydrate();
void b();

//globals
std::string name;
std::string commandLine;
int onRoad = 1; // 1 = True, 0 = False
int steps = 0;
double hunger = 0.0;
double thirst = 0.0;
int energy = 5;

void play() {
    system("CLS");
    std::cout << "Enter your name: \n";
    std::cin >> name;
    system("CLS");
    theme();
    Sleep(350);

    std::cout << " " << name << "'s Roadtrip\n";
    std::cout << "Type \"/help\" for help\n";
    std::cout << "---------Command Line---------\n";
    std::cin >> commandLine;

    while (onRoad != 0){
        //------------------Conditions start------------------

        // Hunger Conditions
        if (hunger = 0){
            if (hunger < 0){
                std::cout << "You can't eat that, you're not hungry.\n";
                b();
            }
        }
        if (hunger > 100){
            hunger = 100;
        }
        if (hunger < 0){
            hunger = 0;
        }
        if (hunger = 100){
            starve();
        }
        else if (hunger > 96){
            std::cout << "You're extremely hungry! If you don't eat something quick you're going to die!\n";
            b();
        }
        else if (hunger > 90) {
                std::cout << "You're very hungry.\n";
                b();
        }
        else if (hunger > 80) {
            std::cout << "You're hungry.\n";
            b();
        }

        // Thirst Conditions
        if (thirst = 0){
            if (thirst < 0){
                std::cout << "You can't drink that, you're not thirsty.\n";
            }
        }
        if (thirst < 0){  
            thirst = 0;
        }
        if (thirst > 100) {
            thirst = 100;
        }
        if (thirst = 100){
            dehydrate();
        }
        else if (thirst > 90){
            std::cout << "You're extremely thirsty! If you don't drink something quick you're going to die!\n";
            b();
        }
        else if (thirst > 75) { 
            std::cout << "You're very thirsty.\n";
            b();
        }
        else if (thirst > 50){
            std::cout << "You're thirsty.\n";
            b();
        }

        //Energy Conditions
        if (energy > 10){
            energy = 10;
        }

        if (energy < 0){
            energy = 0;
        }





        //-------------------Conditions end-------------------



        if (commandLine == "/commands"){
            std::cout << "-Command-          -Action-\n";
            std::cout << " /help              Displays this menu.\n";
            std::cout << " /commands          Displays list of commands.\n";
            std::cout << " /step              Take a step and display total amount of steps.\n";
            std::cout << " /run               Take 5 steps and consume 5 energy.\n";
            std::cout << "                     Doesn't increase hunger or thirst.\n";
            std::cout << " /inventory         Displays inventory.\n";
            std::cout << " /info              Displays stats.\n";
            b();
        }

        if (commandLine == "/step") {
            step();
            b();
        }
        if (commandLine == "/info") {
            std::cout << name << "'s stats\n";
            std::cout << "Hunger: " << hunger << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Thirst: " << thirst << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Energy: " << energy << std::endl;
            b();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << commandLine << " is not a valid command. Type /commands to display commands.\n";
            b();
        }
    }
}
void step(){
    steps += 1;
    std::cout << steps;
    hunger += 5;
    thirst += 5;
}
void run() {
    steps += 5;
    std::cout << steps;
}
void starve(){
    std::cout << "You starved to death!\n";
    die();
}
void dehydrate(){
    std::cout << "You dehydrated!\n";
    die();
}
void die(){
    std::cout << "Steps taken: " << steps << std::endl;
    onRoad = 0;
}
void theme(){
    Beep(600, 200);
    Beep(500, 200);
    Beep(800, 400);
}
//   b takes you back to the command line
void b(){
    std::cin >> commandLine;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "menu.h"
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <windows.h>


int main(){
    menu();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: ** Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrZee.png (need 10 rep to post picture)
This is really weird. I entered /step and it worked, and then i entered /run and it also worked. I don't understand...

Comment: You shouldn't put functions in `.h` files, they should be `.cpp` files that you link with `main.cpp`. Header files should just contain declarations.

Comment: Increase the compiler warning level to its highest and it will tell you about your particular problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your if statements do assignment instead of comparison

```
if (hunger = 100){
            starve();
        }
```

You probably need to change = to ==

Enable warnings while compiling, if you have not already done so.

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
//   b takes you back to the command line
void b(){
    std::cin >> commandLine;
}
```

b doesn't take you back to the command line just wait for a character to be read and then it returns. If you want to go back, you should follow the way you came from. For example exiting play will return you to the menu loop, obviously with menuLoop = 1 so it will exit the whole program but with modifications this is not a bad looping system.

Edit: I've seen what you do mean in the "command line".

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, you have a load of conditions accidentally spelled as assignments.

Also, indeed, the `b()` function is eating subsequent commands.

Maybe you should

1. use `std::getline()` to read a command one line at a time
2. **or** use `std::cin.ignore()` inside `b()` to actually consume until the end of the line

PS. Due to the use of globals I have a hard time verifying the game loop logic. I just know that `/step` after `/step` gets ignored without effect right now. Separate your input from the loop control and try to remove the global variables.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I kind of get what you mean but i don't know how to do it. Please show me an example. Sorry, I'm still new.

Comment: @Ano provided as-is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11895323/ (many issues left unaddressed/untested)

Answer (score 0):

**INFO**
Instead of writing `std::cout` every single time you can just write `using namespace std;` on the beginning after that you dont need to write `std::cout` just write `cout << "" ;`